# referencing variable in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
var items = new Array("one", "two", "three");
var itemsRef = items;
items.push("four");
console.debug(itemRef);
console.debug(items);
```

I really dont get the idea how above `items` and `itemsRef` are same even items added "four" when after `itemsRef` referenced `items`. Isn't it reasonable that `itemsRef` should have only ("one" "two" "three")?

If `itemsRef` keep pointing `items` forever, why do we use such an useless argument like `items = itemsRef`? I am still not getting the idea. Can anybody tell me how this is works and why JavaScript let variables pointing each other forever?

Comment: You're correct about what the code does, but as for why this particular code is written that way, it's pointless as far as I can tell.

Comment: I agree with Wyzard.  You wouldn't typically see that.  Is your goal to make a copy of an array?

Comment: Javascript arrays are assigned by reference: http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Mastering_Javascript_Arrays

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Javascript makes assignments of Objects and Arrays *by reference* instead of *by value/copy*.  That's why you're seeing that behavior.  There's plenty of web documentation about that.

But if your goal is to **copy** an array, do this:

```
var newArray = oldArray.slice(0);
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case itemsRef is not pointing at items, but rather at the object (array) items reference is pointed at. In other word, items and itemsRef point to the same object and not each other.